# MSI - Decrypting Install Script

Tags: windows-installer, encryption, installscript-msi

I'm currently working on building a few portable applications, one of them comes from an MSI installer. The installer seems to execute a program during the installation that I can't seem to trace, so what I'd like to do is to see inside the installer script and see what program it's executing and with what variables.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use a variety of tools to profile.  ProcessExplorer to see programs lauched, parameters, files written to, registry values updated and what not.

Basically you sniff it out and reverse engineer it into more opaque code.

Comment: ProcessExplorer did actually what I wanted, actually! Found the parameters I needed. Thanks!